# Internal Salesforce.com Error in a Query inside a Batch

Tags: batch, query, timeout, gack

**Problem**

i'm having an issue in a Batch Process.
It's have been working properly since January, but in the last days i'm getting an Internal SalesForce Error.
The error line is inside a Query which is called in a Batch process, which executes diary.

**Code:**

```
private static final String INVOICE_NUMBER_FORMAT = '/TEST_'; 
private static Integer dateYear = Date.today().year(); 
private static Integer invoiceNumber = null;

private static void setupInvoiceNumber(){
    String key = dateYear + UpdateInvoiceBatchHelper.INVOICE_NUMBER_FORMAT + '%';
    UpdateInvoiceBatchHelper.invoiceNumber = 0;
    for(AggregateResult result : [SELECT max(Invoice_Number__c)numero 
                                FROM kugo2p__KugamonInvoice__c 
                                WHERE Invoice_N__c LIKE :key 
                                AND Invoice_Year__c > 0 AND Invoice_Number__c > 0 ]){
        UpdateInvoiceBatchHelper.invoiceNumber = (Integer)result.get('numero');
        break;
    } 
}
```

In the end the query seems like this:

```
SELECT max(Invoice_Number__c)numero FROM kugo2p__KugamonInvoice__c WHERE Invoice_N__c LIKE '2015/RR_%' AND Invoice_Year__c > 0 AND Invoice_Number__c > 0
```

Trying in my developer console this very Query sometimes work and sometimes not. 
When it works we get over 4600 rows , but when It doesn't work we get this message: NO RESPONSE FROM SERVER
Today in the morning it did'nt work, but now it's working.

**DEBUG:**

> Apex Debug Log Detail User    Salesforce Administrator    Date    26/08/2015
>   22:03:17 CEST Status  Internal Salesforce.com Error   Application Unknown
>   Request Type  Api Operation   SerialBatchApexRangeChunkHandler Duration
>   (ms)  127.151 Log Size (bytes)    9.069 Log
>   28.0 APEX_CODE,DEBUG;APEX_PROFILING,INFO;CALLOUT,INFO;DB,INFO;SYSTEM,DEBUG;VALIDATION,INFO;VISUALFORCE,INFO;WORKFLOW,INFO
>   22:01:10.251 (251532466)|EXECUTION_STARTED 22:01:10.251
>   (251614875)|CODE_UNIT_STARTED|[EXTERNAL]|01pD0000001Guik|UpdateInvoiceBatch
>
> [...]
>
> 22:01:12.686 (2686519388)|METHOD_EXIT|[1]|UpdateInvoiceBatchHelper
>   22:01:12.686
>   (2686566341)|METHOD_ENTRY|[69]|01pD0000001Guil|UpdateInvoiceBatchHelper.processInvoice(kugo2p__KugamonInvoice__c)
>   22:01:12.686 (2686656124)|SYSTEM_MODE_ENTER|false 22:01:12.686
>   (2686701927)|METHOD_ENTRY|[24]|01pD0000001Guil|UpdateInvoiceBatchHelper.assignNextInvoiceNumber(kugo2p__KugamonInvoice__c)
>   22:01:12.686
>   (2686788797)|METHOD_ENTRY|[48]|01pD0000001Guil|UpdateInvoiceBatchHelper.getNextInvoiceNumber()
>   22:01:12.686
>   (2686854833)|METHOD_ENTRY|[62]|01pD0000001Guil|UpdateInvoiceBatchHelper.setupInvoiceNumber()
>   22:01:12.686
>   (2686987555)|SYSTEM_METHOD_ENTRY|[73]|String.valueOf(Object)
>   22:01:12.687
>   (2687068922)|SYSTEM_METHOD_EXIT|[73]|String.valueOf(Object)
>   22:01:12.688
>   (2688214255)|SOQL_EXECUTE_BEGIN|[75]|Aggregations:0|SELECT
>   MAX(Invoice_Number__c) numero FROM kugo2p__KugamonInvoice__c 
>   22:03:17.086 (127086562646)|SYSTEM_MODE_EXIT|false

No further information in the Debug Log.

I think this issue could be a Timeout Error in the query response, but i don't know how to make a lighter or faster query.
Could anyone help me?

Have a nice day!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a Custom Setting to save the counter (max(invoice_number__c)) and create a Trigger to update the counter and in the batch you can read the value in the custom setting.